# How does MetaMask watch / filter events?

Tags: metamask, infura

If MetaMask uses Infura as their backend, and Infura [cannot watch for events](https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/10), then how does MetaMask manage it?

Answer (score 2):

MetaMask examines the logs for each block and filters them locally. Take a look at https://github.com/kumavis/eth-json-rpc-filters and https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine for details, though the code can be a bit hard to follow.